# Expanding Grid - Positioning button

Tags: javascript, button, grid, position

Howdy i'm new here and in trouble, I don't know what i'm doing and was hoping for some help.
So what i'm trying to do is place this button inside the box with red borders, and still manage to open the content box.

**What i'm aiming for:**
http://i.imgur.com/s6Px9a1.png

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="grid-thumb">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" /></a>

    <button class="grid-thumb-link">Click to open Content box</button>

  </div>
  <div class="grid-content">Success
    <a href="#" class="close-gridder">X
    </a>
  </div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(window).load(function() {

  $(".grid-thumb-link").click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).parent('.grid-thumb').siblings().find('.grid-thumb-link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('.grid-thumb').next('.grid-content').show();
    $(this).parent('.grid-thumb').siblings().next('.grid-content').hide();

    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
      },
      'slow');

  });

  $('.close-gridder').click(function() {
    $('.grid-content').removeClass('gridcontshow').hide();
    $(".grid-thumb-link").removeClass('active');

  });

});
```

**CSS**

```
button.grid-thumb-link {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here's a demo
http://jsfiddle.net/5gcz5tq6/

Comment: I'm on my phone so I haven't been able to play around with the CSS yet but it looks like it could be to do with the float property on the content class. Floats tend to push other objects out of the way regardless of the display and position

Comment: Are you OK to have a fixed height to your `grid-thumb` div?

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, I tried to mess about with the float, couldn't see any difference. And i'm okay with height being fixed Tahir Ahmed.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

1)

```
button.grid-thumb-link { 
 display: block; 
 margin: -30px auto 0 auto; 
 position:relative;
}
```

2)

```
.grid-thumb:hover button.grid-thumb-link { 
 display: block;  
 margin: -30px auto 0 auto;
}
```

3) Add class

```
.grid-thumb a{
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: Nice thank you, that seems to do the job. If there's no better approach i'll go with this.  Do you know how I would go by hiding the button and on image hover display it?

Tried this way, not sure if it's a good solution http://jsfiddle.net/5gcz5tq6/1/ also there's some ugly movement going on when I hover.